# propsvalidation isrequired is not showing warning in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react. I am trying to validate props. As per documentation, if remove isRequired value it shows warning in development mode.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class PropsValidation extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Props Validation</h1>
                <p>{this.props.propArray}</p>
                <p>{this.props.propBoolean}</p>
                <p>{this.props.propFunction}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

PropsValidation.defaultProps = {
    propArray:[1,2,3],
    propBoolean:false,
    propFunction:function(e){return e}
}

PropsValidation.propsTypes = {
    propArray: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    propBool: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    propFunction: React.PropTypes.function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I"m not fully understanding your question but one warning you are going to get is bevause of `propFunction: React.PropTypes.function` it should be `propFunction: React.PropTypes.func`

react expect `func` not `function` for a proptype that is a function

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

that article lists every proptype that is available

Comment: I am going through this link, and try to learn reactjs. As per this tutorial, if i am not assing value to for isRequired variable it shows warnign. Which is currenty not happening. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_props_validation.htm

Comment: If you are assigning them default props as you are in the code snippet you posted then they will always have an initial value and you won't see the warning . Remove the default props and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for helping. But still not getting any warning. Is there any configuration need to do in package.json or webpack.config.js

Comment: This actually happened to me last week, if your NODE_ENV is set to production then React will not produce any warnings. Try this `export NODE_ENV=development ` type that into your bash/console of choice and then recompile and try again

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a warning if you have a prop that is defined as required, is not set and have no default value. If there is a default value, the prop is not empty, therefore the validation for isRequired passes.

Comment: After remove the define value from defaultProps still not getting any warning in console. I am following this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_props_validation.htm) from tutorialpoint.